# How is the rate of water vapor condensate formation related to Relative Humidity, Temperature difference and any other relevant parameters?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, phase-diagram, humidity, condensation

I do not mean to know how they vary (inversly or directly), I need to know if there is a function relation for the rate of condensate formation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is called a [Psychrometric chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychrometrics#Psychrometric_charts).

This chart used in the HVAC industry to calculate relative humidity, wet bulb, dry bulb, etc. There are equations built to mathematically calculate the values in this table, but know that they are modeling empirical data rather than pure theory. So they will be ugly polynomials, and different people may have different equations.

[image: Psychrometric chart from wikipedia]

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the condensation amount, divide the heat removed from the water (using the psychrometeric chart) by the latent heat of the water.
Condensate quantity (lbs) = ((BTU/lb in - BTU/lb out)/lb) / (970 Btu/lb)

For the rate, condensation rate = total heat transfer / heat of vaporization.  Use the equation above and include time
Condensate rate (lbs/hr) = ((BTU/lb*hr in - BTU/lb*hr out)/lb) / (970 Btu/lb)

Are you calculating for a still body like a cold glass of water of air movement like HVAC?  Airflow condensation rate is much easier to calculate- use the psych chart and see the delta in Relative humidity going in and coming out and multiply this by the air flow rate.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/423738)

Comment: Their question is actually very vague, so it's very odd to see your comment state that I did not answer the questions.  Theyeven had to follow up on their initial query to explain themselves.  I believe I have answered the question.  The requestor asked for a function in the their follow up and I gave it.  I even edited my answer to include some actual formulas.  I'm not sure how one can state this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: In this case, use the comment section, not the answer section. The answer section is for answers only. As the standard message above explains, answers shouldn't need further clarification.